# Redshift : Fetch value from table 1 if value exists else pull from table 2

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using Redshift DB.

I have a list of customer IDs stored in a table `customers`

```
Query : select name from customers
```

Based on the purchase data I have a table that has the age of the customer. Table name : `sales`

```
Query : select name, age_group from sales
```

I have another table that has age_group of all customers irrespective of whether they exist in `sales` table. This table is called `customer_profile`

```
Query : select name, age_group from customer_profile
```

I am trying to build a query such that for every customer in `customers` I need to have a column labelled age_group.

**Condition** : If `age_group` value exists in `sales` then it needs to be pulled from `sales` else it needs to fetch the data from `customer_profile` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this

```
SELECT
  t1.name,
  isnull(t1.cp_age, t1.s_age) as age_Group
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      c.name,
      c.age_group,
      cp.age_group as cp_age,
      s.age_group as s_age
    FROM
      customers c
      LEFT JOIN customer_profile cp on cp.age_group = c.age_group
      and c.name = cp.name
      LEFT JOIN sales s on s.age_group = c.age_group
      and c.name = s.name
  ) as t1
```

Comment: @scottmartin . . . Your question mentions no column called `age_group` in `customers`.  Accepting this answer is baffling.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, just used the method mentioned. Did not look into the actual columns used. As that helped accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use union

```
select name, age_group from sales 
where age_group is not null or age_group<>0 
union 
select name, age_group from customer_profile
where age_group is not null or age_group<>0
```

Comment: wouldn't union give duplicates if the same name exists in both tables

Comment: @scottmartin no union will return distinct name it will remove duplicate union all make duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no duplicates in `sales` or `customer_profile`, I would recommend:

```
SELECT c.*,
       COALESCE(s.age_group, cp.age_group) as age
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
     sales s
     ON s.name = c.name LEFT JOIN
     customer_profile cp 
     ON cp.name = c.name AND
        s.name IS NULL;  -- no match in sales
```

This seems like the simplest solution, assuming you have no duplicates.